# Asterisk: Authenticated SIP trunk

Tags: authentication, asterisk, sip

Let's say I have an Asterisk system with a bunch of connections: there are phones (who register itself with `*`) and providers (who wish to establish SIP trunks to put a lot of calls over, with different Caller IDs).

Here is my vision about how calls should be placed over an authenticated SIP trunk: remote end of SIP trunk should send `INVITE`'s with `From` field set to it's identity (username for authentication) and `Contact` field set to what should be Caller ID for this call.

Is that true?

Why I believe this should be true: now, I can not specify `username`/`secret` and `host=<IP>` -- for remote end to register I need to say `host=dynamic`. So, I can setup "pseudo-trunk" as a bunch of extensions, or I need to setup trunk with `host` and no authentication. No authentication is bad.

So, is the above true? And will asterisk match peers by looking at `From` field and use Caller ID from `Contact` field?

If that is not true --- how an authenticated SIP trunk should work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the above (about `From` and `Contact`) may be true, but not required to be true. Will it work or not may depend on actual peers sonfigurations.

When `*` receives `INVITE` request with "wild" `From` (a number that is "not assigned" to any peer), it responses with `Unauthorized`, adding authentication header with no any `username` field (in contrast: when `*` receives `INVITE` with a "valid" peer name in `From`, so it can match peer for incoming call, it includes `username` in authentication header).

This response should be enough to authenticate: the client sends "the same" `INVITE` with the same `From` and `Contact`, and with `Authorization` header with a valid `username` field. Asterisk then matches incoming peer on given `username` value.

Actually, any phone can behave like this; so there is no distinct difference between "SIP phone" and "SIP peer" in SIP. [RFC 3261](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3261.txt) does not contain a single "trunk" word.

ps. Please, if someone will explain things better, I will be glad (and, for sure, accept better answer).

Answer (score 0):

Read "asterisk the future of telephony" o'rellys book

it have all sip protocol nice described.

your qestion can be solved as

```
host=dynamic
defaultip=ip_of_other_side
deny=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0
permit=ip_of_other_side/255.255.255.255
```

or

```
host=
```

on both side and no register string

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+config+sip.conf

Comment: I believe, it can not be solved like this. It is actually about something else? Let's say remote end has it's asterisk behind NAT? -- I will receive a lot of "noise" from that IP. Won't I?

Comment: In general case I do not know what's at the remote side, not always asterisk, not always with no NAT. That's why I am asking "how it (being authenticated) should work".

Comment: please read orelly book. you just missing alot of thing. authentification will not depend of nat or peer type at all.nat=yes will just send packets not to advertised port, but to port from which packet got.

Comment: you are answering another question, i still believe. OK, let me put it in another words: how `From` and `Contact` fields should be filled in `INVITE`s over a SIP trunk (one login/pass, a lot of phones)?

Comment: That depend of  call scenario. You can check that by setup asterisk and do from console "sip set debug on".or reading doc online,book i refer u have example